# How to remove a comma from a particular field in csv file in java

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

My code below is printing the columns with the data. I tried putting `escapeCsv` method of `StringEscapeUtils` but comma does not still go from the name column.

```java
builder.append("Code,CodeName,CodeDepartment");
builder.append(System.lineSeparator());
Set<Entry<String, CodeDetails>> entrySet = sorted.entrySet();
for(Entry<String, CodeDetails> entry : entrySet)
{
    builder.append(entry.getKey());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(entry.getValue().getCodeName());
    StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(entry.getValue().getCodeName());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(entry.getValue().getCodeDepartment());
}
```

Comment: from the [StringEscapeUtils javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeCsv(java.lang.String)) : "If the value contains a comma, newline or double quote, then the String value is returned enclosed in double quotes". It doesn't remove the comma

Comment: Wouldn't this work: `.getCodeName().replace(",", "")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're using the result of `escapeCsv`. You should try something like:

```
builder.append(StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(entry.getValue().getCodeName()));
```

Also, as noted in the comments, this won't remove the comma - it will surround the string with double quotes, which is correct for strings with commas in CSV.

Comment: I tried but stil does not come in the name column as a whole Name it is now surrounded with double quotes in another column(CodeDepartment)

Comment: You might need to double-check all your entries. Your original code first printed the name column, then attempted to escape it - are you still printing both `entry.getValue().getCodeName()` and `StringEscapeUtils.escapeCsv(entry.getValue().getCodeName())`? You should only be printing the latter.